# CTime initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I would like to initialize my CTime object to NULL.

But it doesn't have such a constructor.

What I mean is to initialize it to 00:00:00, then wait until my application fully loaded and a button is pressed to start a certain thread, it will count up automatically.

Also, it is displayed on a cstatic label by the way.

So, could someone offer a hint for me to move on ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for CTimeSpan.  Construct one of them for the initial time, then construct a later one each time your counter fires.  Subtract the earlier one from the later to get the time elapsed.